# Can't seem to see why my Unit Test is failing

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm writing a basic unit test for a system which allows users to amend tickets they've already registered. The unit test which checks a successful amend event works and passes fine however there are two cases which should return None and fail out to the homepage again.

The code I'm testing:

```
def change(database="it"):
    conn: Connection = sqlite3.connect(f"{database}.db")
    config.connection_open = True
    cur = conn.cursor()
    row = take_input('Select ID to amend', 'ID: ')
    # loop back if no row selected
    if row == "":
        change()
    # validation that client is attempting to edit their own file, fails if a client enters a non listed ID number
    if config.usertype == "client":
        cur.execute("SELECT * from requests WHERE ID='%s'" % row)
        # sets the value of rowReq to the Requester value of the row
        rowreq = cur.fetchone()[6]
        # Checks if user is equal to the above value
        if rowreq != config.name:
            print("Error: You do not have permission to edit this file. Returning to Home.")
            # returns to home
            return None
    # if client editing own file or user is staff or manager
    req_column = column(take_input(
        "Select Column to amend \nAcceptable Inputs: Date Added | Time Added | Product | Use Case | Signed off | "
        "Requester | Assigned To | Completed", "Column: ").title())
    print(req_column)
    # checks if the client is trying to assign a ticket to a member of IT staff themselves
    if req_column == "Assigned To" and config.usertype == "client":
        print("Error: You do not have permission to assign tickets, please contact an IT Manager or Staff member "
              "for an update on your tickets assigned status")
        return None
    new_data = input("Enter new data for " + str(req_column) + " field of ID " + row + "\n\nNew Data:")
    data = (str(new_data), int(row))
    # queries if input is correct
    accept = take_input(
        "Confirm amend " + str(column(req_column)) + " on ID " + row + "to: " + new_data + "? (Y/N)\n").lower
    if accept() == "y":
        cur.execute("UPDATE requests set [" + str(column(req_column)) + "] = (?) where ID = (?)", data)
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()
        config.connection_open = False
        print("Amend Completed")
        return True
    else:
        print("Amend Cancelled")
```

The Tests

```
class TestAmendData(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        config.name = "ZAVALC"
        config.usertype = "client"

    # This one fails
    @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["1"])
    def test_should_return_none_on_no_permission_to_edit(self, mock_input):
        self.assertIsNone(amend.change(database="test"))

    def setUp(self):
        config.name = "BRAYC"
        config.usertype = "client"

    # This one fails
    @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["1", "Assigned To"])
    def test_should_return_none_on_client_assigning_to_IT(self, mock_input):
        self.assertIsNone(amend.change(database="test"))

    def setUp(self):
        config.usertype = "manager"

    # This one works
    @patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["1", "Pro", "Amended Value", "y"])
    def test_should_amend_value_on_correct_input_as_staff(self, mock_input):
        self.assertTrue(amend.change(database="test"))
```

The Error Output

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\Assignment\Test\UnitTest.py", line 53, in test_should_return_none_on_no_permission_to_edit
    self.assertIsNone(amend.change(database="test"))
  File "C:\...\Assignment\functions\amend.py", line 34, in change
    req_column = column(take_input(
  File "C:\...\Assignment\core\return_home.py", line 14, in take_input
    response = input(input_query)
  File "C:\...\mock.py", line 1075, in __call__
    return self._mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\mock.py", line 1079, in _mock_call
    return self._execute_mock_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\mock.py", line 1136, in _execute_mock_call
    result = next(effect)
StopIteration
```

Any pointers on where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated

Comment: this one: `@patch('builtins.input', side_effect=["1", "Assigned"])` shouldn't the value be `"Assigned To"`?

Comment: @Anentropic The line that effects `req_column = column(take_input(
        "Select Column to amend \nAcceptable Inputs: Date Added | Time Added | Product | Use Case | Signed off | "
        "Requester | Assigned To | Completed", "Column: ").title())` runs some RegEx to pull that it means Assigned To

Comment: this part `if row == "": change()` should probably `return change(database)`

Comment: isn't the help text wrong then, if it says "Assigned To" is the acceptable input?

Comment: When you say those two tests fail, is it the `self.assertIsNone` assertion that fails?  the call is returning `True` instead?

Comment: @Anentropic It's purposefully lax to allow for minor spelling issues. The failure isn't that it's returning the wrong value but the test doesn't seem to get there. I've added the output from the traceback (Which i forgot to add!) Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement a loop.

Comment: Not only does the recursive call waste stack space, but it will open the wrong database if  you passed an explicit value the first time instead of using the default `"it"`. Recursion is not just a kind of `goto` statement. (Worse, you aren't recursing because the connection failed, but because the user didn't supply input. You very much do *not* want to reopen the database in that case.)

Comment: Also, do *not* use string formatting to create a SQL query. Create a paremerized query instead using whatever facilities your SQL library provides.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for the suggestion and I will take that on board for this, How would you recommend refactoring the code to fix the unit testing then?

Comment: Heavily. Anything that relies on the result of an `input` statement should probably be a separate function that takes that result as an argument.

Comment: The traceback looks like `StopIteration` is raised when your test case tries to call the mocked `builtins.input` more times than were mocked values in the list you pass to `side_effect`.

Comment: ...so it seems like the `if rowreq != config.name:` check is negative and it does not take the early return path, instead falling through to the next line `req_column = column(take_input("Select Column to amend...`